# Youtube video useless after the last update

Tags: video, google-chrome, youtube

After some updates recently, Youtube videos now run extremely jerkily. Almost like they are swimming in superglue. It also slows my computer down to a speed akin to a snail on diazepam. Running Ubuntu 12.04.01 and using Google Chrome Version 26.0.1410.63. 
Firefox seems to run videos fine, but it's not my preferred browser. Cheers 
JJ1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the browser itself, since chrome doesn't use the flashplayer installed systemwide, but its own integrated flash player. That's why videos work fine in firefox. Hve you tried reinstalling chrome, or downgrading it to a previous version?

Comment: I don't know how to downgrade Chrome to the previous version. Why don't Google test these updates thoroughly before releasing them into the wild? Surely they know there are Ubuntu users out there? I'm surely not the only one encountering this problem?